# java newbie question

Tags: java

if I have something like this

```
Map<String, Foo> foos;
...

Foo f = foos.get("key1");
foos.removeAll();
```

Am I still able to do  `String s = f.getSomeProperty();`

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: Note that by Java convention, classes start with an uppercase character while methods are in lower camel case.  And as Java is case-sensitive you need to get them right; none of the three lines in your code fragment would compile, for this reason...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`foos` holds only references to objects, not full objects. If you get something from `foos`, you get reference to that object and you can modify it. If you remove all elements from `foos`, then it no longer holds any reference, and those objects can be garbage collected only if there is no other references to that objects.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are. You just cleared the map, but the local variable `f` still holds a valid reference to the `Foo` and you still can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that String (note the capital S) is the name of the Java class which represents character strings.  But yes, yes you are.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is yes. `f` contains a reference to the object that `foos.Get("key1")` returned (assuming it is non-null). When you remove all from `foos`, you're simply removing the references from the `foos` object - you are not actually destroying the data that `foos` used to contain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes f is Foo object and if Foo have some property that is string use it 
Code:

```
Map<String, Integer> mp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
mp.put("key1", 48);
mp.put("key2", 50);
mp.put("key3", 52);
mp.put("key4", 54);
mp.put("key5", 56);
mp.put("key6", 58);
Integer mytemp = mp.get("key1");
mp.clear();
System.out.println(mytemp);
```

Out:

```
48
```

that see mytemp is your f that is full object not only pointer